# Print statement is not working in view controller method when run the UI Test case in Xcode 14.0

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I have created a custom framework and inside that all the logs are recorded when we  initialise the framework.

Now I have integrate that framework inside a demo project and write UI test case for the same.

When I add the breakpoint inside the method then only logs are getting printed in the console while running the  UI test case .Otherwise it don't print the logs in the console when break point is not added.

I don't know why thing is happening. I need logs for analysis purpose.

Could you please help me .

Print statement  is only working when adding break point in the view controller class.

[image: 1]

![2]

[image: 3]

Comment: You should include code as text and not as an image. You have a warning in the console, have you investigated that to see if it is relevant to your issue? If you are so dependent of logging maybe you should use a proper logging solution instead of using `print`?

Comment: Yes . I have proper logging solution but I don't know the reason why logging is happening  only when we add break points in the view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your UI test code runs in a separate process outside of your app process. The default state shows the debugger for the UI test process, and not your app process, and will only show print statements written in the UI test code. The print statement you wrote seems like it’s a part of your app code.

If you hit a breakpoint in your app code, the Xcode console switches to show the debugger for your app, as opposed to the debugger for your UI test, which is why you see the print statement there.